# Error downloading compressed shapefiles in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, zip, shapefile, r-sf

I want to download a shapefile which has 4 files with extension ".shp", ".shx", ".dbf", ".prj"
Put those files in a temporary directory called `tem_dir`,  finally compress the folder and download.
It generates the shapes files for me but when I compress it it doesn't, it appears to me that it can't find the files in the specified directory.
My code is the following

```
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(zip)
# Define la aplicación Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Agrega un botón para descargar el archivo Shapefile comprimido
  downloadButton("download_zip", "Descargar Shapefile comprimido")
)


datos <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  nombre = c("Objeto 1", "Objeto 2", "Objeto 3"),
  longitud = c(-76.5, -76.6, -76.7),
  latitud = c(2.5, 2.6, 2.7)
)

sf_datos <- st_as_sf(datos, coords = c("longitud", "latitud"), crs = 4326)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
output$download_zip <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
          paste("temp_shapefile", ".zip", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
          # Crea un directorio temporal para almacenar los archivos shape
          list_zip <- c("temp_shapefile.shp", "temp_shapefile.shx", "temp_shapefile.dbf", "temp_shapefile.prj")
          temp_dir <- tempdir()

          # Escribe los archivos shape en el directorio temporal
          st_write(sf_datos, dns= "temp_shapefile.shp",layer = file.path(temp_dir, "temp_shapefile"), driver = "ESRI Shapefile", delete_dsn = TRUE)
          # Crea el archivo comprimido en la ruta especificada
          zip(file = file, files = file.path(temp_dir, list_zip))
          # Elimina el directorio temporal
          unlink("temp_shapefile", recursive = TRUE)
      },
      contentType = "application/zip"
  )}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to test the answer provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707760/download-a-shape-file-from-shinybut I get the following error:

```
Warning in file.remove(zip_file, shp_files) :
  cannot remove file 'C:\Users\CHI\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiErG44/temp_shapefile_shp.zip', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I would like to download the shapefile in a zip file using the downloadHander function

Comment: I would start by switching to gpkg instead of shp. It is a standard single file format accepted in any GIS and would probably simplify your workflow